# Page Reloading in React despite event.preventDefault()

Tags: reactjs, get, reload, event-listener

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function Form() {

    const [signalLength, setSignalLength] = useState('');
    const [signalVector, setSignalVector] = useState('');
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('./wowSuchEmpty.png');

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        console.log("Button Press.")
        event.preventDefault();
        const res = await axios.get(`/generate/random?signal_length=${signalLength}&signal_vector=${signalVector}`);
        console.log(res)
    }
    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="font-[Inter] text-center font-bold text-[3rem] my-5">Constellation Diagram Gen</h1>
                <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mx-auto w-[50%]">
                        <label className = "text-[Inter] my-2 text-[1rem]" htmlFor="signal-length">Signal Length: </label>
                        <input 
                            className = "bg-[#FAF9F6] rounded-lg border-2 px-5 py-2" 
                            name = "signal_length" 
                            id = "signal-length" 
                            placeholder="e.g. 7" 
                            value = {signalLength} 
                            onChange={(e) => {setSignalLength(e.target.value)}}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mx-auto w-[50%]">
                        <label className = "text-[Inter] my-2 text-[1rem]" htmlFor="signal-vector">Signal Vector: </label>
                        <textarea 
                            className = "bg-[#FAF9F6] rounded-lg border-2 px-5 py-2" 
                            name = "signal_vector" 
                            id = "signal-vector" 
                            placeholder="e.g. [[1,2,3],[2,7,9]]" 
                            value = {signalVector} 
                            onChange={(e) => {setSignalVector(e.target.value)}} 
                        />

                    </div>

                    <div className="w-[50%] mx-auto my-5">
                        <button type = "submit" className="bg-[#FAF9F6] border-2 rounded-lg text-center mx-auto px-5 py-2 transition all ease-in-out hover:text-[#FAF9F6] hover:border-[#2C3333] hover:bg-[#2C3333]">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <img className = "mx-auto" src = {imageUrl} width = {500} height={500} alt = "OWO MUCH GRAPH!"></img>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

The above is a form component that is sending a get request to Python Flask powered API. The Request is being sent out perfectly but the page is reloading every time I click the submit button despite the fact that I have put e.preventDefault() in handleSubmit().

Please Help, I do not know why this happening.

I have tried everything from changing the button type from "submit" to "button" to changing the API fetch method from fetch() to axios.get(). I have tried onSubmit, onClick and other event listeners but none of them seem to solve the problem. I have also tried changing the function from synchronous to asynchronous and back again to no avail.